# Confusion about double sum reduction

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I am in the process of understanding an article on loop antennas due to some heavy math. Even though this topic may be related to microwave/antenna engineering I figured it was better to ask here, since it is the math that seems to be the problem. I have the following component of a vector potential, which has been derived in the article
$$A_r(r,\theta,\phi)=\frac{\mu ka\sin\theta}{4i}\underset{m-n=2q\\q=0,1,\dots}{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}}I_n\sin(n\phi)\frac{n\left(\frac{k^2ar\sin\theta}{2}\right)^{m-1}}{\left(\frac{m-n}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)!}\frac{h_{m-1}^{(2)}(kR)}{(kR)^{m-1}}\quad (1),$$
where $h_{m-1}^{(2)}$ is the spherical Hankel function of the second kind of order $m-1$. The expression above assumes an arbitrary current distribution in the term $I_n\sin(n\phi)$. However, I'm looking for the special case where the current is cosinusoidal meaning $I(\phi)=I_p\sin(n\phi)$ leading to $I_n=0\, \mathrm{for}\, n\neq p$. My work so far has been to replace the inner sum over $n$, which means I have the expression
$$A_r(r,\theta,\phi)=\frac{\mu kaI_p\sin(p\phi)\sin\theta}{4i}\sum_{\substack{m=1\\m-p=2q\\q=0,1,\dots}}^\infty\frac{p\left(\frac{k^2ar\sin\theta}{2}\right)^{m-1}}{\left(\frac{m-p}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{m+p}{2}\right)!}\frac{h_{m-1}^{(2)}(kR)}{(kR)^{m-1}}\quad (2).$$
The author of the article suggests another way of writing it, but he does not show how to do it. He simply states, *"Under these circumstances, it may be shown that (1) reduces to"*
$$A_r(r,\theta,\phi)=\frac{\mu kaI_p\sin(p\phi)\sin\theta}{4i}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{p\left(\frac{k^2ar\sin\theta}{2}\right)^{2m+p-1}}{m!\left(m+p\right)!}\frac{h_{2m+p-1}^{(2)}(kR)}{(kR)^{2m+p-1}}\quad (3).$$
I have a strong feeling that the expression can be written like this when you change where the index $m$ starts from, however, I am having a hard time figuring out why this is so. Furthermore, I think it has something to do with the condition $m-p=2q$, but I am not too sure about this.

I hope some of you have an idea as to how the specific reduction of the double sum takes place. Equation (3) is the wanted expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get expression (3) with $m$ starting from $1$ and with an extra factor of $m(m+1)/2:$

Equation (2) seems correct. The sum in (2) can be written as
$$
\sum_{q=0}^\infty\sum_{m=2q+p}^\infty \frac{p\left(\frac{k^2ar\sin\theta}{2}\right)^{m-1}}{\left(\frac{m-p}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{m+p}{2}\right)!}\frac{h_{m-1}^{(2)}(kR)}{(kR)^{m-1}}\,.
$$
Writing $m'=\frac{m-p}{2}$ this becomes
$$
\sum_{q=0}^\infty\sum_{m'=q}^\infty \frac{p\left(\frac{k^2ar\sin\theta}{2}\right)^{2m'+p-1}}{m'!\,(m'+p)!}\frac{h_{2m'+p-1}^{(2)}(kR)}{(kR)^{2m'+p-1}}\,.
$$
If we swap the summation signs and relabel $m'$ to $m$ this becomes
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{q=0}^{m} \frac{p\left(\frac{k^2ar\sin\theta}{2}\right)^{2m+p-1}}{m!\,(m+p)!}\frac{h_{2m+p-1}^{(2)}(kR)}{(kR)^{2m+p-1}}\,.
$$
The summand can be pulled out of the inner sum because it does not depend on $q\,.$ Therefore, this is
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{m(m+1)}{2} \frac{p\left(\frac{k^2ar\sin\theta}{2}\right)^{2m+p-1}}{m!\,(m+p)!}\frac{h_{2m+p-1}^{(2)}(kR)}{(kR)^{2m+p-1}}\,.
$$

Comment: I am a bit confused as to why the summation runs from $q=1\rightarrow m$ in step 3. 

Thanks for the help. Even though the extra factor of $m(m+1)/2$ is there, I am still grateful for your help, since this is almost the exact form I asked

Comment: Right it should run from $q=0$. Will fix it . But it won't get us rid of that extra $m(m+1)/2$ term.

Comment: I was actually more confused about why it goes to $m$ and not $\infty$.

Comment: Just draw a little $2d$ picture that shows the $q's$ and the $m's$ we are summing over. When the inner sum is over $m$ and starts from$q$ what does that mean to the swapped summation? It is a confusion happening a lot when people do Fubini.

Comment: Alright, I have little experience with sums but I just looked up the Fubini principle and at first glance it makes sense. Thank you for your help with the additional questions.